# Como criar páginação por seta?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando fazer páginação por seta, utilizando ajax, mas não estou conseguindo...

Páginação normal eu consegui (que é mostrando os números) mas com seta, não estou conseguindo.

jQuery:

```
 var paginacao = {
    iniciar: function(pagina){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "paginacao.php?pagina=" + pagina,
            success: function (result) {
                $('.all').html(result);
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    paginacao.iniciar(1);
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include '../assets/app/config.php';
$conexao = new Conexao($config);
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

$sqlPaginacao = $conexao->conectar()->query("SELECT * FROM noticias"); //Pega resultado geral
$total = $sqlPaginacao->num_rows; // Conta os registros gerais

$qtd = 1; // Quantidade exibida por página

$paginas = ceil($total / $qtd); //Cálculo de quantas páginas vai dar

$inicio = ($qtd * $pagina) - $qtd; //Mostra o inicio

$sql = $conexao->conectar()->query("SELECT * FROM noticias LIMIT $inicio, $qtd"); //Pega resultado real
while($mostra = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<article class='news'>{$mostra["titulo"]}</article>";
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<?php
include '../assets/app/config.php';
$conexao = new Conexao($config);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .arrow {
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -moz-flex;
            display: -ms-flex;
            display: -o-flex;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            float: left;
            margin:  5px 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .arrow.disabled { opacity: 0.5; cursor: default; }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="all">

    </div>
    <div class="arrow back disabled"><</div> <div class="arrow next">></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não entendi, quais setas?

Comment: Esse código está um pouco incompleto, sugiro trazer mais detalhes principalmente do seu html onde de fato é apresentado a paginação.

Comment: Justamente, não sei continuar os códigos, coloquei o HTML, para ver se fica mais claro.